# BAT code: how to access a directory and run Python script

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a .bat file that will run automatically during a startup on my server. I want the .bat file to open CMD, go to a given directory and then run a Python script from there.

Once the Python script has been activated, I want a separate CMD window to run a shutdown timer so that after a given time (t=86400, daily) the system will reboot. This is my way of making sure the file will continue to run after I disconnect to my server.

My current code is

```
@echo off
start cmd /k cd C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/
python scraperv2.py
start cmd /k shutdown -t 86400 -r -f
```

This code will go to the directory C:/Users/Administrator/Documents but it will not run the Python script. Please note that Python is set as a PATH variable.

What do I need to do to get this script to work?

Comment: what error do you get ? is scraperv2.py in the PATH ?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish by using `start ..`?

Comment: There is no specific error. It simply just does not run the script. My output when running the file is 2 CMD windows. Screen 1 has accessed the given directory. Screen 2 has run the shutdown timer command. However, there is no sign of the python script being active

Comment: I used `start` because I thought it was a prerequisite for opening a program. I removed it but the issue remains

Comment: `start cmd /k cd C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/` will start a new instance of cmd.exe but will not change the directory of the current one. Why you just dindn't used `cd /d "C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/"`

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you are able to run `python` from cmdline using any path to make sure it is actually in your environment, then simply do:

```
@echo off
python "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\scraperv2.py" && shutdown /r /f /t 86400
```

Which will call python and the script from directory and if successful (`%errorlevel%==0`), it will do shutdown command. If `%errorlevel%` is anything other than `0` it will not run the shutdown command.

If you really want to do the `cd` then simply do this:

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents"
python scraperv2.py && shutdown /r /f /t 86400
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work now:

```
@ECHO OFF
START CMD /K "CD C:/Users/Administrator/Documents && python scraperv2.py"
START CMD /K "SHUTDOWN /R /F /T 86400"
```